# Opening/Closing keyboard triggers BottomSheetBehavior's OnSlide Callback

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheetBehavior in my main activity to constantly show a bottom drawer.

When I open and then close the keyboard (when pressing an EditText and then pressing Back), the method "OnSlide" gets triggered:

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset)
  {
    // my code
  }
}
```

I have code in this function that runs when the user slides the drawer up and down with his finger. I don't want this code to be run when the keyboard comes up and back down. It doesn't make sense that it's being called. How can I prevent keyboard changes from running the code in this function ?

I tried:

1. Changing in my AndroidManifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` which essentialy does what I want, but removes useful functionalities which I had added (enabling scroll while keyboard is up).
2. Listening to soft keyboard changes to only execute code when changes are not occuring which doesn't work since OnSlide is called after keyboard is fully hidden (see code below).

Keyboard change listener:

```
mContentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout()
    {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mContentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int screenHeight = mContentView.getRootView().getHeight();

        // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
        // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
        int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

        // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
        mKeyboardIsOpen = keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15;
    }
});
```

Comment: What did you find out about this?

Comment: I ended up not using that callback, and just listened for the state (open or close) to trigger a fade-in or fade-out. Not the best solution, but couldn't figure a fix.